# crash when setting image in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I'm using a piece of code I have used several times before to load an image into a UIImageView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"png"]];
    [self.imgWeather setImage:img];
}
```

For some reason I get a SIGABRT when I hit [self.imgWeather setImage:img];

The image and UIImageView seems to be initialized correct.

Any idea what's going on?

**[EDIT]**

It seems to be crashing when I setImage to nil. Not good. I just looked at the stackTrace and can see a 'doesNotRecognizeSelector' exception:

```
#9  0x02554651 in objc_exception_throw ()
#10 0x0240842b in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#11 0x02378116 in ___forwarding___ ()
```

The imgWeather is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgWeather;
```

any idea what this mean?

Comment: Why not `self.imgWeather.image = img;`?

Comment: Can you post the full call stack of the crash?

Comment: Jacob: I already tried your suggestion. Same result
Adam: I will post that later on

Comment: I think the only viable reason for a crash is that your imgWeather view is deallocated at some point. Are you properly retaining it? What does the @property line for imgWeather look like?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgWeather;
Should be fine, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If self.imgWeather is nil - nothing bad would happen. I suspect self.imgWeather is not nil but it is not a UIImageView anymore and you are hitting a different object or just some random memory block(perhaps it has been released, there might be a memory problem in your app).

Does

```
[self.imgWeather setImage:Nil];
```

create a problem as well?

Comment: Hi Krzyspmac, 

I think you are right. It seems to be crashing when I setImage to nil. Not good. I just looked at the stackTrace and can see a 'doesNotRecognizeSelector' exception: 


#9  0x02554651 in objc_exception_throw ()
#10 0x0240842b in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#11 0x02378116 in ___forwarding___ ()



any idea what this mean? 

The imgWeather is defined as: 

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgWeather;

Comment: I had made a very stupid error, and had not used @synthesize on imgWeather. Thanks for the suggestion. Made me look in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgWeather;
```

Your imgWeather is an outlet. Make sure it is properly linked in the IB.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to make absolutely sure your UIImageView object is initialized.  One easy way is simply to add some code to check it for *nil* and print a line to the console with the result.

Comment: That way `self.imgWeather` would be `nil` and because messaging `nil` is OK in Obj-C I don't see why this would be the cause of the SIGABRT.

Comment: either UIImageView or UIImage is nil

Comment: No, you CAN set a UIImageView's image to nil (it means "no image") so even if the image was nil, it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer this syntax:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]
```

FWIW.  Give that a try just for the heck of it.

Comment: That's not the same, and results in caching of the image in much different ways. Unless this is a small image that is used repeatedly throughout his application, I recommend against using this.